# Ajax jQuery contact form not working properly

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with Ajax contact form, specifically the php file.

Ajax code:

```
var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email + '&message=' + message + '&submitted=true&isAjax=1';
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $('.form').attr('action'),
            data: dataString,
            success: function (msg) {
                $('.img.ajax-loader').css({ visibility: 'hidden' });

                if (msg == 'Mail sent') {

                    $('.response-output').html(contactFormVars.contact_form_error).removeClass('mail-sent-ng, validation-errors');
                    $('.response-output').html(contactFormVars.contact_form_success_message).addClass('mail-sent-ok');
                } else {
                    $('.response-output').html(contactFormVars.contact_form_error).removeClass('mail-sent-ok, validation-errors');
                    $('.response-output').html(contactFormVars.contact_form_error).addClass('mail-sent-ng');
                    $('.contactForm .submit').removeAttr("disabled");
                }

                $('.contactForm .submit').removeAttr("disabled");
            },
            error: function (ob, errStr) {
                $('.response-output').html(contactFormVars.contact_form_error).removeClass('mail-sent-ok, validation-errors');
                $('.response-output').html(contactFormVars.contact_form_error).addClass('mail-sent-ng');
                //Activate the submit button
                $('.contactForm .submit').removeAttr("disabled");
            }

        });
        $(".ajax-loader").css("visibility", "hidden");
        return false;
```

PHP:

```
<? php
if ($_POST) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message']; 
    //send email 
    mail("test@mail.com", "Subject" .$email, $message); 
    return true; 
} 
?>
```

I made a simple php script mail, emails reach the recipient, but I have a problem on how to return the value of a return to Ajax script to show a message that the message was sent.

Sorry for my poor English, I hope I described my problem in a clear manner. I will be grateful for your help. Thank you.

Comment: _specifically the php file._. Can you show that file? What is not working with the displaying of your message? No message at all or?

Comment: <?php
if($_POST){
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];

//send email
    mail("test@mail.com", "Subject" .$email, $message);
 return true;
}
?>

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: in your php file return status codes like 0 for success or 1 for failure you cannot check the success status using string in javascript:)

Comment: better to share the url if possible

Comment: the you should use the comparison `(msg == 1)` instead of `(msg == 'Mail sent')`

Answer (score 0):

change the PHP script

```
if($_POST){ 
    $name = $_POST['name']; 
    $email = $_POST['email']; 
    $message = $_POST['message']; 
    //send email 
    mail("test@mail.com", "Subject" .$email, $message); 
    echo "Mail sent"; 
}
```

adding a trim() on the JS as

```
if (msg.trim() == 'Mail sent') {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $('.form').attr('action'),
        data: dataString,
        success: function (msg) {
            $('.img.ajax-loader').css({ visibility: 'hidden' });
            if (msg == '1') {
               // do what you want
            }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$isAjax = isset($_POST['isAjax']) && $_POST['isAjax'] == "1";

$mailSent = dealWithEmail($name, $email, $message);

if ($isAjax) {
    if ($mailSent) {
        echo "Your message has been sent"; // This will be the message received
    } else {
        echo "Your message has NOT been sent"; // This will be the message received
    }
} else {
    // redirect to "email sent (or not)" page
}
```

Comment: Thank you. In this case, it worked, just returns me a message that the email has not been sent, ie: contactFormVars.contact_form_error

Mail came and it should return a value: contactFormVars.contact_form_success_message

I do not know what to do next :-)